# WPF TabItem doesn't lose focus

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol

I have a tabcontrol binded the an observable list. Eveything look to be perfect until I select a tab. Once selected, the tab doesn't lose its focus and the selected tab is not available. They are not any message in the Output Window.

Here is a screen shot just before clicking the tab:

[image]

And here is a screen shot after (with the problem):

[image]

Any idea about how to resolve this problem or any hint to be able to debug this kind of behavior?

Comment: I've seen this when doing WinForms/WPF Interop, especially with the Prism toolset.  I ended up converting everything to 100% WPF to fix it... I don't know if this sounds like your scenario.

Comment: This has been solved by try and error tonight. The problem was that when the tab is open, it was openning the SAME tab and it seems that you can't add the same model object in two tab without having the tab hanging. Now it works... Thanks guy to have looking up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that when the tab is open, it was openning the SAME tab and it seems that you can't add the same model object in two tab without having the tab hanging.